# C# How to read Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, object, key

i try to passing javascript array to code-behind using object in code-behind, now i should get each value

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void getData(object[] data)
{
     ...
}
```

this is array from javascript :

```
var data = [["5","John"],["6","Marteen"]];
```

after i pass into code-behind :

```
data            {object[137]}
--[0]           {object[1]}
----[0]         Count = 8
------[0]       {[id, 5]}
------[1]       {[Name, John]}
```

i have to get ID and Name, i can't simply read like javascript,
ex : data[0][0]["Name"] = "John";

now i just try to read using foreach and i still can't get the value

```
foreach (object[] item in data)
{
    var array = (object[])item;
    foreach (var str in array)
    {
       /*how to get the value*/
    }
}
```

so how should i do to get that value using index?

thanks before

Comment: An object can be anything, what kind of object? Show the class declaration and how you initialize `data`.

Comment: Instead of using object, use defined classes, is data a json object deserialized?

Comment: i just pass an array from javascript , should be store into database, so im using code-behind to do this, i just want to get the value of ID and Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript array in server-side is nothing but a plain string. Its unstructured data. To get your object structure back you need to define corresponding C# class.  and then as Sayse suggested use Json serializer, something like JSON.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.